# Plain vi (not vim): Can't delete a line in insert mode: Is this behavior required by POSIX?

Tags: vi, posix, standard

In the non-`vim` implementations of `vi` I've worked with, it's not possible to delete a line while in insert mode. `vim` does allows it—but it's my understanding that `vim` is not POSIX-compliant in its default configuration.

Is a POSIX-compliant `vi` implementation not supposed to allow the deletion of lines in insert mode? Please quote the relevant parts of the standard where possible.

Comment: I remember the `vi(1)` in BSD 4.2 acting like that. It makes sense, either you are inserting (writing stuff into the file) or you are doing commands on the contents. Not that that counts as POSIXly correct...

Comment: It seems very unlikely that POSIX would dictate something you *cannot be able to do* in this case.  However, if it's not something the standard *requires*, then an implementation which doesn't do it is compliant (as is one which does do it).  Generally standards are about positive and not negative capabilities. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html <- Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not required. It is up to the implementation to decide, as the behavior is unspecified. In implementations which allow it, the contents of the current line after the newline is erased must be erased as well. The POSIX specification for `vi` states the following ([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#tag_20_152_13_88)):

> #### Input Mode Commands in vi
>
> In text input mode, the current line shall consist of zero or more of the following categories, plus the terminating <newline>:
>
> [...]
>
> It is unspecified whether it is an error to attempt to erase past the beginning of a line that was created by the entry of a <newline> or <carriage-return> during text input mode. If it is not an error, the editor shall behave as if the erasing character was entered immediately after the last text input character entered on the previous line, and all of the non- <newline> characters on the current line shall be treated as erase-columns.